# soot on a plane

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

This is the nacelle (?? I guess, I'm just someone who takes plane trips ??) of a DeHavilland Dash 8-400 that I flew on (as a customer) from Toronto to Boston last week. I noticed the soot around the bottom of the exhaust, which seemed unusual to me; I'm guessing that this is the result of the smoke in the air from Quebec wildfires (this plane is owned by Porter Airlines and had presumably been operating in the northeastern US and southeastern Canada for the previous few days).

A few closely related questions:

- Is this soot build-up unusual, or is it typically there and I just haven't noticed?
- If it's unusual, is it likely a result of operating in a smoky environment?
- Does operating in wildfire smoke impose an extra maintenance/cleanup requirements for commercial aircraft?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty [standard](https://www.skytough.com/post/what-do-planes-emit) build up and has nothing to do with operating in and/or around wildfires. You can see identical build up [here](http://www.kathrynsreport.com/2018/02/nokair-bombardier-q400-incident.html), [here](https://www.picfair.com/pics/010583438-bombardier-dash-8-q400-aircraft-engine-exhaust-outlet-and-wingtip), and [here](https://de.dreamstime.com/abgasd%C3%BCse-der-propellerflugzeug-maschine-image114333009). What you are looking at is the engine exhaust and is a prime location for exhaust/soot/oil/grime buildup.

Smaller piston planes are [particularly notorious for this kind of build up](https://piperowner.org/talk/discussion/151641/degreasing-the-planes-belly-what-do-you-use).